# How do I handle a result from a mysqli query in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
// Create Connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

//Check connection
if($mysqli->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected Successfully";



// Retrieve data from database 
$result= $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Basically I need to know how to handle this data now.
In the database I have a format:

```
Column 1: Name
Column 2: HighScore
```

I'm trying to display this on a webpage in a table so I need the query in a format which I can handle, what I have so far is:

```
// Start looping rows in mysql database.
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $rows['name'] . "|" . $rows['score'] . "|";

    // close while loop 
}
```

However, I don't believe I am using the `mysqli_fetch_array()` correctly as it isn't entering the while loop.

Comment: Hi, if your column name is 'Name' you have to write $row['Name']. It's the same for score, if column name is 'HighScore' you have to write $row['HighScore']

Comment: A more suitable duplicate would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index.

Comment: @Qirel Added that also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fieldnames returned from this function are case-sensitive.

```
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $rows['Name'] . "|" . $rows['HighScore'] . "|";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you using mysqli. So to fetch reuslt as in your case use as object oriented style:

```
$result= $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10");

while($rows=$result->fetch_assoc()){
  echo $rows['name'] . "|" . $rows['score'] . "|";
}
```

so not procedural style this:

```
$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)
```